# Angular API access for internal use - Username/Password or long lived access token

Tags: angularjs, authentication, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

I have a series of ASP.NET Web API(v2) endpoints I need to access from internal programs (internal to my organization) using Angular. These endpoints are secured and require an access token with the proper role in order to access the endpoints. I see two options.

1. Create a long lived access token that the clients can use to access the endpoints
2. Use a Username/Password to request an short lived access token. Each time the clients needs access to the endpoint they would need to request a token first.

   Is one of these any better than the other? With the Username/Password approach an extra step is introduced but if the token is compromised it is short lived as opposed to a long lived access token.

Comment: I usually set the token as one day long .. so it's in the middle ..

Comment: How do you handle API calls that build up the applications interface? For example, perhaps populating a User list or perhaps a list of products? Do you leave these endpoints open to anonymous use or do you require the access token to have permissions for these endpoints as well?

Comment: it dependends if the data are sensitive..another option i use somtimes is that my app have to retrive a token every day (not an authentication) and in everyrequest my backend check if the token is correct .. hope it can help you